# Alternatives to touch screen interactions on Kitchen Ops UIs

Tags: touch-screen, tablet, kitchen

I'm designing a Kitchen Ops app that will be used by staff in the kitchen of a restaurant. The client already plans on using iPad's for this, and each of the staff will have a mounted device next to them displaying the meals they need to prepare.

Given the nature of cooking, food preparation and the kitchen environment in general, i'm expecting other factors like greasy, oily or wet hands when touching the displays to interact with the UI. I'm exploring how to overcome potential problems that maybe come up related to these. or what other ways could the UI or the devices be adjusted to overcome this?

Comment: If this is going to be a problem, I would suggest you don't use iPads. I expect there are plenty of providers out there that can provide better devices suited for these environments. Where the screens will be more resilient.

Comment: Even if you would add an Apple Pencil or a mouse with the iPad, it can still be tempting to touch the screen with a finger. I sometimes see people touch normal computer screens when they are focused on the task and forget about the type of device they are dealing with. Not sure if that's going to be a problem though.

Comment: The most complex options i believe would be implementing 'Air Gestures' or 'Voice commands' but since you probably have technical limitations(See your 'how to let users know that updates are not in real time' question), i would avoid iPads, they are NOT DESIGNED for heat/humid/greasy/volatile environments like a kitchen. If your client really insists on that, you can wrap the iPad in layers of plastic wrap(Yes, the one you use for food, you probably have it in the restaurant kitchen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be very hesitant using regular iPads in a restaurant environment.
Things top of mind:

**Steam and liquids**
Steam is more damaging than water on electronics (smaller water particles = easier to slip in between the cracks) and humidity related damages are not covered by warranty.

**Capacitive screen**
iPads and other general consumer touch surfaces react on conductors. Our fingertips are conductive, that is a good thing! Too bad, we are made out of water, which is highly conductive. Even more bad, restaurants are full of water, liquids, and other ingredients made out of water. Try rubbing some water on your phone and then touch it. Often, it will "tap" somewhere completely off compared to where you intended to.

**Gloves**
Unfortunately, gloves are almost the only thing in the kitchen that is not conductive. Touch gloves when preparing food? They usually contain granular metal parts. Not recommended risking dropping that in the food.

**Sturdiness**
There are a reason the POS (Point of sale - touch enabled machines for taking orders and payments) at McDonald's are butt-ugly: they can withstand extreme stress from whatever comes at it. Year after year. My local fast food chain has had the same machines for over 10 years. Even if the users should mainly just look at the iPad, how long will it last an average kitchen? Dropping utensils on it, getting heavy cream poured over, cleaned with high-alcohol based solutions, constantly bumped into by people and objects? Then, we have the stressed, hard-pressing fingers that will hammer on it almost around the clock. You know how your grandparents almost touch their new iPhones to death with finger punches? Something like that.

**"This sounds awfully negative!"**
Sorry, just trying to save your behind. Unless the iPad is only for a stationed cashier, who will only use it for processing payments, answer customer emails, or watch "Building an underwater cave" YouTube clips, I would advise trying another device instead.

**What to do?**
Don't use an iPad. You are getting paid (I hopefully presume) to be the expert, so dare be the expert and tell your client that you will not let them make a mistake because you have made your due diligence and found out X, Y, and Z. Then, say that you will happily help them research other types of touch devices instead. If it will cost more than one iPad? Yes. Will they only need to buy each iPad once? No.

**General UX experience around touch in restaurants**
From my previous clients, I have learned that people always expect the device to react to any kind of pressure input. Especially pens. Restaurant people love touching screens with their pens, credit cards, utensils, knuckles, elbows (yes!) and so on.

Oh, and the UI will need to be very practical with an extreme overview. No second clicks allowed, staring at a screen is no ones job at a restaurant. A famous story around my UX local community is about the consultancy firm which made a reservation system with three clicks to confirm arrived dinner guests. That was two clicks too many, so the staff took a marker pen and simply crossed over the names (on the expensive iPad screen!) and then wiped it off with an industrial grade strong solution at the end of the day.

More learnings include that whatever you do in the UI, make it almost twice as big as you estimate it. People are stressed as heck, the regular 45px hit area will be too small. Texts will need to be shortened, truncated, large. Color? Contrast is king, no 50 shades of Grey. Make it WCAG-AAAAA.

Good luck! You got this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not clear with your question, why your client insists on ipad. But if thats the case, see if you can help ( or add more complexity? :)) by adding a mini apple keyboard wrapped in plastic and design application suitable for keyboard use. May be, you can mount keyboard on a hanging/sliding/revolving tray which can be easily moved out of the working area to avoid getting it between everytime.